# how will this code work and what will be the output of this

Tags: c++

What can be the minimum and maximum value of number?
int number = -10 + rand()%20;

What will be the minimum and maximum value of number and how?

Comment: First figure out the minimum and maximum of `rand() % 20`, then use the ancient power of arithmetic to figure out the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:
0 <= (rand()%20) < 20
then:
-10 <= -10 + (rand()%20) < 10

be careful of operator precedence
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence